# How i do .When switching languages, the error message content appears depending on the active language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How i do .When switching languages, the error message content appears depending on the active language.
Expected result :warning message should displayed in Arabic if language is Arabic
Actual result : warning message displayed in English although  language is Arabic

```
import { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Alert } from "reactstrap";
import { useLanguage } from "../contexts/LanguageContext/languageContext";

interface Props {
  error: unknown;
  onDismiss?: () => void;
}

export const ErrorMessage = ({ error, onDismiss }: Props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>();
  const { getText } = useLanguage();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }, [error]);

  const friendlyErrorMessage = useMemo(() => {
    if (typeof error === "string") return error;
    if (error instanceof Error) return error.message;
    return JSON.stringify(error);
  }, [error]);

  const title = useMemo(() => {
    if (typeof error === "string") return error;

    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      if (error.code === "ERR_NETWORK") return getText("networkError");
      return error.name;
    }

    return getText("error");
  }, [error, getText]);

  return (
    <Alert
      className="mb-3"
      color="danger"
      toggle={() => {
        setIsOpen(false);
        onDismiss?.();
      }}
      isOpen={isOpen}
    >
      <strong>{title}</strong>
      <hr />
      <pre className="mb-0" style={{ whiteSpace: "break-spaces" }}>
        {friendlyErrorMessage}
      </pre>
    </Alert>
  );
};
```

Expected result :warning message should displayed in Arabic if language is Arabic
Actual result : warning message displayed in English although  language is Arabic